# Syntax Error in Calling a method from another class

Tags: c#

How may I call a method in another class from another class in a separate file.  The files are in the same directory.  I tried calling this SMAMethod method

```
namespace myBackEnd
{
    public class SMA
    {
        public static Models.DateClose SMAMethod (Queue<Models.DateClose> 
        queue, int period)
        {
            decimal average, sum=0;
            Models.DateClose dateClose = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < period; i++)
            {
                dateClose = queue.Dequeue();
                if (dateClose != null)
                    sum += dateClose.Close;
            }
            average = sum/period;
            dateClose.Close = average;

            return dateClose;

        }
    }
}
```

When I call the SMAMethod in I get the red squiggly line with the hover over text " SMAMethod does not exists in the current context"

```
SMAMethod(movingAverageQueue, 10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the class that it's in.  Try this:

```
myBackEnd.SMA.SMAMethod(movingAverageQueue, 10);
```

`myBackEnd` is the `namespace`, it will be unnecessary if your other class is in the same `namespace`.

`SMA` is the class that your method exists in.  This is required.